# IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding get only english phrases

Tags: php, curl, post, get, watson

The small for IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding get only phrases in english when received by POST (in php).
When I POST french, spanish or portuguese don't work.

My code:

include_once('JSON.php'); 
$json = new Services_JSON();

//Get Parameter 
$protocol = utf8_decode(($_GET['protocol']) ? $_GET['protocol'] : $_POST['protocol']);
$report = utf8_decode(($_GET['report']) ? $_GET['report'] : $_POST['report']);
$class =  utf8_decode(($_GET['classified']) ? $_GET['classified'] : $_POST['classified']);

//Call Watson

```
    $report = strtoupper($report);         

    $username = 'xxxxxxx';
    $password = 'XXXXX';
    $url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27&text=Helloethics&features=entities,sentiment,keywords';

    // Set post arguments for call
    $post_args = array(
        'text' => $report
    );

  // Set header arguments for call
    $header_args = array(
        'Content-Type: text/plain',
        'Accept: application/json'
    );

  // Set options for REST call via curl
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxxxxxxx:XXXXXXX");        
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);

    $status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Actual REST call via curl and cleanup (closing) of curl call
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($curl);
```

The POST/GET works only when the prashe is english, but other languages Watson return:

The POST works only when the prashe is english, but other languages Watson return:

{ "language": "pt", "entities": [], "warnings": [ "keywords: internal server error", "sentiment: internal server error" ] }

But, when I use a LOCAL VARIABLE, OK,works. Please, help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In line 
$report = utf8_decode(($_GET['report']) ? $_GET['report'] : $_POST['report']);

Just remove utf8_decode.

Works!